# Сразу 2 post запроса в одном c#

Tags: php, c#, request, live

Существует серверная часть на PHP и клиент на C#. Мне нужно сначала провести "верификацию", потом основной запрос, всё в рамках одного запроса, чтобы не терять результат "верификации". 
Что я подразумеваю под "верификацией"? Сервер выводит строку через 'echo', клиент принимает, обрабатывает, и отправляет результат, который сервер вновь обрабатывает, и "принимает" клиента за своего, тогда происходит основной запрос с несколькими параметрами.
Основной запрос отправляет несколько параметров и снова получает ответ. На том подключение заканчивается.

Вопрос: как реализовать это и на C#, и на PHP?

Comment: Если работа с Web, то ваш подход как по мне странный. Обычно такое делается с помощью токена авторизации или чего то подобного, что дается временно клиенту сервером. Клиент его запоминает и при каждом запросе отправляет в заголовке этот токен.

Comment: А у вас это хоть в каком-либо виде работает?

Comment: Это сделано во имя безопасности, про токены я думал, но их ведь можно перехватить. Если представить, что я параноик, мой вариант можно реализовать? P.S. Работает, но без верификации

Comment: А что мешает перехватить вашу задумку? Вам нуден идентификатор клиента (IP, может токен, может еще что), имея его ваш сервер понимает что с вами делать. Что мешает злоумышленнику перехватить и подменить этот идентификатор? Что злоумышленнику помешает вообще скопировать ваш сервер и сделать фейк страницу "идентификации"? Если вы параноик - используйте локальную сеть и не выходите в интернет.

Comment: По моему алгоритму сервер должен генерировать уникальную строку, которую клиент обработает и выдаст другую уникальную строку, с помощью которой и произойдёт рукопожатие. Сервер и клиент "узнают" друг друга.

Comment: Вы изобретаете те же токены (JWT например). Делайте его временным и вот весь ваш алгоритм. Но я не вижу проблем в его перехвате.... В наше время можно все что угодно взломать, отловить и так далее.

Comment: Вы изобретаете велосипед. Всё за вас уже придумали. Используйте шифрованное подключение и токены, вы не придумаете ничего более безопасного.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял. Спасибо.